# Check if a check box is already checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i currently have a jquery change function in place that makes a input text box grey and read only when a user selects the check box. However im looking to perform a check when the page loads to see if the check box is already selected, additional to this current function?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#redflag2").change(function () {   
        $('#new_contracted_support_hours')
            .prop("readonly", this.checked)
            .toggleClass("greyba", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do if it is checked?

Comment: if is checked perform .prop and .toggleclass that is currently defined in the change function i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function flag_changed(flag) {
  $('#new_contracted_support_hours')
    .prop("readonly", flag.checked)
    .toggleClass("greyba", flag.checked);
}


$(document)/ready(function() {
  $("#redflag2").change( function() { flag_changed(this); } );
  flag_changed(document.getElementById('redflag2'));
});
```

Put your logic into a named function and then invoke it directly during your $(document).ready()

Answer (score 3):

Use [**is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [**:checked**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#redflag2").is(':checked')) {
        modifySupportHours();
    }
    $("#redflag2").change(modifySupportHours);

    function modifySupportHours() {
        $('#new_contracted_support_hours')
            .prop("readonly", this.checked)
            .toggleClass("greyba", this.checked);
    }
});
```

Comment: cheers! it works by graying out the text box but however does not make it read only like it does when i physically click the check box?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {    
function do-what-you-want-function-name (e) {
        $('#new_contracted_support_hours')
        .prop("readonly", this.checked)
        .toggleClass("greyba", this.checked);
    }

    $("#redflag2").change(function () {
        radioException($(this))
    });

    $("#redflag2").each(function () {
        radioException($(this))
    })
})
```

Function with name and two call for the two use.